# ColorStateList in code set

Tags: android, styles

1. I want code set the ColorStateLit , checked = true show theme_color
   color and false show Color.BLACK , I want use the Methods2 setting ,
   But you can't achieve !  We usually use color resource in the xml
   style:

   ```
   Method1:

   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/theme_color"/>
   <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@color/black"/>
   </selector>

   Mehtods2:

   int[][] states = new int[2][];      
   states[0] = new int[] {};
   states[1] = new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked};        
   int colors[] = new int[]{Color.BLACK,theme_color};      
   ColorStateList csl = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
   ```